# MinGW compiled exe - libgcc_s_silj-1.dll missing

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I'm trying to run an .exe file on windows, which was probably compiled under MinGW x86, and I'm getting an error that libgcc_s_silj-1.dll cannot be found.

As the .exe is not from myself, I cannot recompile it or whatever is suggested on other SO answers.

I installed MinGW x86 on my computer, but there is no libgcc_s_silj-1.dll file deployed either. Where can I get this dll from?

Answer (score 0):

visit [MinGW-w64 Project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) There are some personal builds targetting win32 on it. `libgcc_s_silj-1.dll` can be found in the archive